# SQL Date Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, t-sql

How do I format a data in SQL to read like this:
Monday, November, 23 2009

Comment: select 'Monday, Nobember, 23 2009' from XXX   ;)

Comment: @tster: `FROM DUAL` would at least work on Oracle & MySQL :p

Comment: @bochur1: You should tag your question with the brand of RDBMS you use, because the answer varies from one to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is for SQL Server (T-SQL)**

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) + ', ' + DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ', ' + CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Just replace GETDATE() with the date variable

[Learn more about DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258263%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

The usual suspects:

### For MySQL:

```
DATE_FORMAT(t.date_column, '%W, %M, %d %Y')
```

[DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

### For SQL Server:

```
DATENAME(dw, t.date_column) +', '+ DATENAME(mm, t.date_column) +', '+ CAST(DAY(t.date_column) AS VARCHAR(2)) +' '+ CAST(YEAR(t.date_column) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

[DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258263%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

### For Oracle:

```
TO_CHAR(t.date_column, 'DAY, MONTH, DD YYYY')
```

[TO_CHAR](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

Comment: What version of SQL Server does DATENAME have an underscore in it?

Comment: Word of advice - the SQL Server statement won't execute unless you cast the DAY and YEAR values as varchar, nvarchar etc. Upvoters should probably check an answer has correct syntax or can execute before voting - no offense to you OMG.

Comment: Gah, I keep getting caught by SQL Server's lack of implicit datatype conversion.  No offense taken - I really appreciate you letting me know.

Comment: @Scozzard, it's even nicer if upvoters edit the answer to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using MySQL,

DATE_FORMAT(field_name, '%W, %M, %d %Y')

Answer (score 0):

Which provider are you using?  In SQL Server, it would be w/CONVERT.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).