# Remove time from a date/time string using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sql, date, time

What is an efficient way to strip the time from this returned dataset using jQuery? I need the time to exist in the database because of ordering purposes however I need to display only the date.

`<adopt_date>Apr 25 2013 2:41PM</adopt_date>` is an example of a result from my Web Service.

Here is how I currently usethe information if it helps:

`var adopted_date = $(this).find('adopt_date').text();`

Where $(this) is dataset.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be doing this [in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1794563/901048), then, not in jQuery. Exactly *how* you do it in SQL depends on what database you're using.

Comment: If you're able to access the SQL table, why not just properly format the date before outputting it?

Comment: Or you could do it with the script language (PHP?) that writes the date instead.

Comment: I asked a question as to how to do something. Why is there so much conjecture as to what I should or should not be doing?

Comment: Because most of us are programmers. We like to look for and offer the **easiest** solution to a problem.

Comment: While this may be an easier way, if I wanted an easier way that would have been included in my question. Being that the first sentence reads, "What is an efficient way to strip the time from this returned dataset using jQuery?" I don't really understand why all the conjecture is necessary. Regardless, I got my answer. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I don't see any "conjecture" among the answers. Comments though are so smart for communicating! I'm usually glad to get hints, I wasn't aware of :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("adopt_date").html(function (index, value) {
    return value.replace(/\d{1,2}:\d{2}(AM|PM)/ig, '');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xDwAX/)

Comment: THANK you! This is exactly what I needed, not 10 reasons why I shouldn't do what I'm doing. You rock, Palash!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with plain JavaScript:

```
adopted_date = adopted_date.replace(/ [0-9]*[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]A*P*M/,'');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2b7Bm/1)**

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have no control over the data you are receiving, and only have the option to parse this on client-side, here's a pragmatic approach:

Split with space and pop last one.

```
var adopted_date = $(this).find('adopt_date').text().split(' ');
adopted_date.pop();
adopted_date = adopted_date.join(' ');
```

Translated in English, this means

- Split the adopt_date's text by a space character (becomes an array)
- remove the last item from the array using .pop() (which happens to be the time)
- then join the array back into a string, using a space as a delimiter

At the end of the day, lacking coffee, I'd spit this out first, call it a day, and next day, nice cup o' coffee, and improve this with regular expressions like the other answers.

Comment: While another answer did work, can you explain for me like I was five how this works?

Comment: Awesome! I went searching for .pop() in the API and could only find an obscure reference. Today I learned, thanks Terry!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late, but anybody coming here for the answer, here is a one liner:
`adopted_date.toDateString();`