# MySQL DATE_FORMAT() issue

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-formatting

I have date on MySQL table on the format of  `Fri Oct 30 09:50:37 2015`, when I try to format using `DATE_FORMAT(`delv_time`,'%Y-%m-%d')` it return `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794563/sql-date-format)

Answer (score 2):

That's not as date as far as MySQL is concerned. That's a *string*. You need to convert it into a date using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). Then you can use `DATE_FORMAT()` to get only the date portion of the datetime.

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(delv_time,'%a %b %d %T %Y'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```